# Win Form: SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I added the following piece of code to a save button:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{                
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
    writer.Write(twexit.Text);       // twexit is previously created  
    writer.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

When I type the name of the file and click save, it says that file does not exist. I know it does not exist but I set `FileMode.Create`. So, shouldnt it create file if it does not exist?

Comment: This code have to work. I did tested it myself and it does work.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option [`CheckFileExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.checkfileexists.aspx) in `SaveFileDialog` which will cause the dialog to show that message if the selected file doesn't exist.  You should leave this set to false (this is the default value).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, twexit.Text);
```

instead of lot of code with stream. It create new file or overwrite it.
File is class of System.Io . If you want to say if file exist, use

```
File.Exist(filePath)
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
     SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();

        dlg.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        dlg.Title = "Export in CSV format";

        //decide whether we need to check file exists
        //dlg.CheckFileExists = true;

        //this is the default behaviour
        dlg.CheckPathExists = true;

        //If InitialDirectory is not specified, the default path is My Documents
        //dlg.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;

        dlg.ShowDialog();
        // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
        if (dlg.FileName != "")

        //alternative if you prefer this
        //if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            //&& dlg.FileName.Length > 0)

        {
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(dlg.FileName);
            streamWriter.Write("My CSV file\r\n");
            streamWriter.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            //Note streamWriter.NewLine is same as "\r\n"
            streamWriter.Write(streamWriter.NewLine);
            streamWriter.Write("\r\n");
            streamWriter.Write("Column1, Column2\r\n");
            //â€¦
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        //if no longer needed
        //dlg.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can you explain why you check the filename for empty string? from what i know, you can only Cancel the dialog, but you cannot click the Save button without actually putting a file name

Comment: also, you dont seem to check the dialog result.